# Elements will not add to C# list

Tags: c#, list

I just finished a C# totorial and thought it would be a cool idea to get the most popular type of computers using lists. I was able to get it to work exept the only the most recent element will be added to the list.

```
namespace computerDatabase
{
    class program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                List<string> computerName = new List<string>();

                Console.Write("Who is your computer manufacturer: ");
                string cName = Console.ReadLine();
                computerName.Add(cName);
                if (cName == "list")
                {
                    foreach(string s in computerName)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    computerName.Add(cName.ToLower());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: look at the first statement *inside* the loop. If you expect to print more than one element, how are you ever going to get that to happen when each iteration of the loop *starts* with an empty list?

Comment: Also do you want to add item to the list twice if it’s value isn’t `name?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Jon, you re-initializing your list for every iteration, nullifying any input added to the list. You also do not need to specify a capacity for the list in the constructor as it will grow automatically. I've corrected the relevant parts for you:

```
List<string> computerName = new List<string>();

while (true)
{
    Console.Write("Who is your computer manufacturer: ");
    string cName = Console.ReadLine();

    if (cName != "list")
        computerName.Add(cName.ToLower());
    else
    {
        foreach(string s in computerName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is better to delete this line. Because it is added to the list twice `computerName.Add(cName);`

Comment: @hosseinsabziani I was not sure about this as the second addition was lower case but I agree, its most likely not want he wanted.

Comment: If cName == "list" it shouldn't be added to the list at all, because it represents a command rather than a computer name.